# Animation node addon overwrite keyframes standard animation

Tags: animation, keyframes, animation-nodes

I've just installed the animation node addon in Blender 2.83 and I've found that the animation result overwrite every other previous animation of the object while rendering but not in the viewport.
Here's an example:
let's say you have a text object with an animated transformation on the Z axis made with standard keyframe method. 
You want that text to be the actual frame number.
So you use animation node to input in the text object the actual frame number (pretty straightforward).
Now hit play and see the result. Nice! It works!
So you hit render/animation and... ooops! The text object stay still as long as the node animation is running.

Do you guys have a solution? Is it intended to work like this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% what I had was the what you're asking ^ but I had a similar thing where i had keyframed location and used animation nodes for rotation. even though i never enabled Transform output for location it still became 0 location when rendering even though in the viewport it looked like it moved perfectly.

my solution was to take the object transform input node and plug it's location into the object transform output node.
which seems weird but hey it worked for me and maybe it'll work for whoever reads this in the future.

Comment: Thank you Jonny, I will take a look at your answer, it makes sense to me. I'm pretty sure in the end I solved my problem somehow, but I can't remember how. Thanks again.